# JavaScript development with Aptana using Outline View

Tags: javascript, editor, aptana

Has anyone programmed JavaScript on Aptana Studio? I am having problems with the Outline View. It does not show the methods of classes. For example:

```
var test = new Class({
 variable: 0,
 something: function() {
 }
});
```

the result is that the outline does not show variable nor something -function. It only works when I define a function like:

```
function something() {
}
```

but that is not enough. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. Aptana seems like a nice IDE for JS, but this sucks bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, Aptana's outline view never views the contents of closures. It will view the contents of public objects or global functions, however.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug...  Should be fixed in 3.0.4

see 
[jira_appcelerator__APSTUD-2799](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2799)